# /etc/hosts configuration error , ping not working

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, kerberos, mit-kerberos

i am newbie to ubuntu plus kerberos , trying to configure kerberos in my vm ubuntu by i am not able to pass the step 2 in configuring hosts .below are the files. i am in the process of learning so please help .

my problem is when ping localhost i am getting response but when i ping monarch or krb1 i am getting error .

```
    hguna@ubuntu:~$ ping -c1 localhost
PING localhost (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.034 ms

--- localhost ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.034/0.034/0.034/0.000 ms


   hguna@ubuntu:~$ ping -c1 monarch
    PING ubuntu.spinlock.hr (192.168.7.12) 56(84) bytes of data.

    --- ubuntu.spinlock.hr ping statistics ---
    1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

**my etc/hosts looks like below**

127.0.0.1        localhost

192.168.7.12    ubuntu.spinlock.hr ubuntu krb1.spinlock.hr krb1 monarch.spinlock.hr monarch

my etc/hostname look like below

ubuntu

please helpe me as to where i am doing wrong

**note -** Both the kerberos server and the client will be installed on the same machine. However, to differentiate between client and server roles, the client will be referred to as monarch.spinlock.hr and the server as krb1.spinlock.hr. in the etc/hosts file

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question. Try [ubuntu.se].

Comment: thats the help you can do really , you can see my tag it is very appropriate i dont know where you are getting that programming part

Comment: Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic You'll find more people who can help you on [Ubuntu.SE] or [UNIX.SE].

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most likely in the Kerberos configuration.

The name resolution here is working fine.  You enter `ping -c1 monarch` and the `/etc/hosts` translates that to the IP 192.168.7.12 as is should.

Potential issue is that you have your local hostname `ubuntu` defined as a remote IP as well.

Comment: so what do you suggest the fix  that would be ? in etc/hosts file  if i remove ubuntu it will throw a error saying unknown host

Comment: I have not setup Kerberos myself, so the following are generic suggestions based on my experience with VMs: Review your network setup.  Ensure you can pink a known good host using its IP address.  Change your local hostname to something unique (ubuntu-test-ker) to ensure no conflicts with other hostnames.  Ping the VM from another server.